# data is not loading in tableView and not updating profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, api

I am new in objective C.Execute this Program ON Clicking on button"Click here to sell your Gold now" 
It will lunch you to dashboard.In dashboard select Transaction History.I have fetchNewHothistory function in TransactionHistoryViewController.m file responsible for fetching data from url and displaying it onto the viewcontroller file

```
-(void)fetchNewHothistory
{
    NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                  target: self
                                                selector:@selector(mytimerChecking:)
                                                userInfo: nil repeats:NO];

    NSMutableDictionary *paramDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [paramDict setObject:@"ios" forKey:@"request"];
    [paramDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentUser.user_id] forKey:@"user_id"];
    [paramDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.currentLimitNew] forKey:@"limit_start"];

    [GeneralWebservices webserviceMainSplashCall:paramDict webserviceName:Webservice_TransactionHistory OnCompletion:^(id returnDict, NSError *error) {

        if ([returnDict[@"success"] intValue] ==1)
        {
//                        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
//                        [alert setTitle:@"RECORD FOUND"];
//                       // [alert setMessage:returnDict[@"message"]];
//                        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
//                        [alert show];

            [history addObjectsFromArray:returnDict[@"data"]];
            self.currentLimitNew=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",returnDict[@"limit_start"]] ;
            [historyTableView reloadData];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
            [alert setTitle:@"RECORD FOUND"];
            //[alert setMessage:returnDict[@"message"]];
            [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
            [alert show];
        }
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
        [historyTableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];
        [historyTableView.infiniteScrollingView stopAnimating];

    }];

}
```

Issue -1
Record found but nothing displayed on Viewcontroller on selecting the Transaction History.The How to display record onto viewcontroller?

Issue -2 
In on selecting Profile the ProfileViewController.m is executed .On updating the user profile .It does not updates .It remain buffering .How to perform profile update .
you can download the project from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1daW4veZAI21b8TqKFHauSFTboHKJceaG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: issue - 1 :- Check, have you set delegate and datasource of tableview and also check tableview height.

Comment: I have checked delegate and datasource of tableview.They are rightly connected .I have also checked tableview height

Comment: Is `webserviceMainSplashCall:webserviceName:OnCompletion` completion block executed in main thread? Because modifying the UI needs to be done in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

      [historyTableView reloadData];

   });
```

Comment: In TransactionHistoryViewController.m at end of function fetchNewHothistory i pasted these lines .Still the record is not displayed .What i can do to display record? Please help